# Can A cause B with B preceding A in time?

Tags: logic

I am wondering whether or not A can cause B with A occurring after B. Something about this seems nonsensical. But is it **logically** contradictory?

If it is not logically contradictory, does this mean we also can’t **rule out** that A can cause B with A occurring after B?
Something about A causing B seems to necessarily imply A preceding B in time and hence it seems to be a contradiction.

An interesting follow up is this: If A causing B necessarily implies A preceding B in time, does this also rule out or atleast make meaningless the notion of atemporal causes?

Comment: From a physics perspective, time is unidirectional and so A cannot cause an event B in the past. However, if we assume time is bidirectional- capable of two degrees of movement, forward and backwards. Then there is nothing inherently contradictory about  event A causing some event B in the past. It's no more a logical contradiction than asking, can a car hit someone behind it, if it moves in reverse?

Comment: This called [retrocausality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retrocausality), and some prominent physicists, like Feynman, entertained the possibility of it in describing quantum fields. Closed timelike curves in relativity allow some [forms of time travel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novikov_self-consistency_principle), so it would also be theoretically possible. But by and large, retrocausality is considered fanciful.

Comment: Michael Dummett wrote a paper called "Bringing About the Past" in which he argues that backwards causation is not impossible or unthinkable in principle. Philosophical Review 73, (1964) pp. 338-359.

Comment: Consider this situation: some event A' caused B, but event A' is invisible, and event A is a very direct visible consequence of A'. Event A is such a direct, inevitable and well-known consequence of A' that most people conflate A and A' when talking about them. Thus it becomes natural to say "B is a consequence of A" even though A was witnessed after B. For example: lightning, and thunder. Thunder comes a few seconds later, but we closely associate it with lightning.

Comment: @Stef The OP is not asking about misperceptions, but about actual causation.

Comment: @IñakiViggers Thank you for your comment

Comment: Have you seen magic shows? I have, they're fascinating to watch. I try not to learn/explain the how of the illusions magicians (correction, *conjurers* per the late great The Amazing James Randi) use to entertain their audience. C'mon guys ... and gals, ... don't ruin it for the kids.

Comment: My terse answer to the title is "no". It is logically contradictory insofar as it contradicts my preferred definition. Such binary relations on events can be constructed, but I don't think "causal" is the right word for those relations.

Comment: Yes and no. See Aristotle's [Four Causes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_causes)

Comment: Fantastic question that shows how the space of knowledge&thinking that once belonged to philosophy(and religion), nowadays is fully covered by physics&maths.

Answer (score 2):

From a physics perspective, it is *mathematically* possible, as shown by Einstein's paper on the tachyon anti-telephone. Einsteinian Relativity shows that, *if* FTL motion occurred, where one could either communicate information or physically travel FTL, in some frames of reference one would observe the signal's reception as happening before the signal was sent. A clever but simple arrangement of such tachyon antitelephones would allow one to receive a message before they ever sent that message. Same for superluminal warp drives and wormholes.

Now, most physicists don't take these situations to be something we'll ever observe in our world. But tachyons from Special Relativity or closed-timelike-curves in General Relativity are not contradictory: one can use the math to produce these situations.

Epistemic possibility is relevant here, since I'm relying on mathematical possibilities from physics. Given what we know, tachyon particles are not likely to occur if ever. Quantum Field Theory (QFT) predicts that a quantum field with imaginary mass *never* produces tachyon particles, but instead represents an unstable vacuum. Superluminal warp drives and wormholes are different. Nothing outright forbids such phenomena (yet), but they rely on negative mass-energy in astronomical quantities (which has never been observed).

Important to note here, is that even if someday we learn that tachyon particles and CTCs are forbidden by the laws of physics, their *logical* possibility is secured by the consistency of the math that allowed us to even hypothesize them.

So to answer your question: no, they are not logically impossible, since the math permits them in both SR and GR. We are getting a picture from QFT that at least tachyon particles will probably never be observed. Closed-timelike-curves are an open question: we'll need a theory of quantum gravity to get a definitive answer on that. Yet, even if that happens, it just means our universe won't have these phenomena (logically possible, but physically impossible).

Comment: One of the distinctions that might enrich this answer is "logical possibility" vs "epistemic possibility", although this answer is already on-topic as-is.

Comment: @Galen modified answer to reflect that, good call! Feel free to correct me if I made an error in my reference to epistemic possibility.

Answer (score 1):

One quick argument that it can't be logically contradictory is that people can enjoy movies about time travel.  If, by definition, we considered all causal-level correlations between A and B to always have the cause before the effect, then we would mis-interpret the evident direction of causation portrayed in those movies.  If this were logically contradictory, while watching the beginning of Back to the Future, we would infer that Marty McFly's arrival in 1955 was the cause of his departure in 1985, rather than the other way around.

The reason why we don't mis-interpret those movies is almost certainly that most people have an innate ["interventionist" viewpoint of causation](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/making-things-happen-9780195189537?cc=us&lang=en&), where the intervention is considered to be the cause.  Consider flipping a lightswitch, connected to a lightbulb in a sealed box.  Suppose you were later shown a video (taken from inside the box) proving that the state of the bulb was always perfectly correlated with the position of the switch one second in its future.  How would you interpret this?  Would you infer that the bulb caused the future switch position, according to the usual time-order of causation?  Doubtful.  You would more likely infer that you had somehow been able to control the past, to cause the state of the bulb one second into the past.  After all, your intervention is at the switch, not the bulb, so the switch is naturally viewed as the cause.  (Putting the bulb in the box prevents bilking paradoxes, allowing one to better imagine this scenario – but the topic here is logical coherence, not physical plausibility.)

The philosopher most closely associated with taking retrocausality seriously is Huw Price; some of the chapters in [this book](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/times-arrow-and-archimedes-point-9780195117981?q=huw%20price&lang=en&cc=us) are focused on applying interventionist causation to such scenarios.  Emily Adlam has also been recently [writing](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=RlTqjZMAAAAJ&citation_for_view=RlTqjZMAAAAJ:Zph67rFs4hoC) on this topic.  (I'm not a philosopher, but I take it seriously over on the [quantum foundations](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.92.021002) side of the aisle.)

Comment: I forget the phrasing and don't have my copy of [Pearl 2009](http://bayes.cs.ucla.edu/BOOK-2K/) handy, but for your interest in further reading I think he discusses a conjecture of there always being a statistical time consistent with physical time.

Comment: Yes, I think I remember that.  Pearl posed it as an open puzzle/question, why interventionist causation always seemed to line up with temporal order, when one can define interventionist causation without any reference to temporal order.  Nevertheless, his point was that it's not inconceivable that it would line up the other way, it just never seems to in real life.

Answer (score 1):

A bank hires guards that shoot to kill anyone trying to rob the bank. Bank robbers stay away in droves. Including one bank robber who didn’t rob a bank in the morning because the guard started his job that day - in the afternoon.

So the guard starting in the afternoon caused the robber to not rob the bank in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

As far as we know, all of the particles that form the Universe, including all of the particles responsible for the transmission of forces, are moving through spacetime in a direction of increasing time, so a chain of events is always from earlier events to later ones.

I would encourage you, my friend, to be extremely skeptical of any mention of faster than light travel or closed timeline loops in connection with changing events that occurred in the past. Such ideas are based on a fundamental assumption about reality which is entirely unsupported by mainstream physics, namely that if you, say, were to go back to last Tuesday, you would find the Universe there as it then was, a rather odd idea given that the Universe has since moved on and is here where you left it before you headed back in time. According to modern physics, particles move on trajectories through spacetime, known as world-lines, and since you are a collection of particles, you move along a world-line too, which means that at a later time you no longer occupy the position you did at an earlier time; hence if you were to find a way to go back to that earlier time, you would certainly not find your old self there.

Likewise with closed timeline curves. Were you to travel round one, you would do just that- travel around it. You would no more meet your old self on completing a lap than you would if you were to complete a lap on a running track.

Comment: Wouldnt CTCs in theory allow you to meet your old self on a lap though, because the "track" in such a scenario involves a temporal loop, so when you're at the start of the loop you're also at the starting time?  From what I've always understood, the math just says that if such a loop existed, it would be self consistent, so if you went back in time to see yourself, that event would have necessarily already happened in the past.  Time travel doesnt allow you to change anything in the past.

Comment: @JMac no! Think about it... your 'old self' is no longer at the starting time. Your old self is you, and has moved on through time.

Comment: What do you mean "your old self is no longer at the starting time"?  Your "old self" cant leave its "starting time".  Existing in the present doesnt mean you didnt exist in the past, so travelling from the present to the past doesnt logically suggest that the past you wouldnt still be there.  The past you _has_ to still exist in the past when you travel back, or else you wouldnt exist in the present and someone who doesnt exist cant travel in time, or do anything.

Comment: @JMac, no, you are still not getting it. The atoms that comprise your body move forward through spacetime. A particle that is at t=0 has moved forward to t=1 a second later, and is no longer at t=0.

Comment: Your atoms moving "forward through spacetime" doesnt mean that they no longer exist at the previous point in space and time, just without a CTC there is no forward path that gets you to the point in space and time that was also in your past.  But that's exactly what a CTC does.  It's a path "forward" in time and space for you, that brings you to a point in spacetime that was also your past.  See for example the [Novikov self-costistency principle] (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novikov_self-consistency_principle).  In the example given, a ball goes through a CTC to hit itself

Comment: (Cont.) so that its trajectory brings it into the CTC in the first place.  As long as there is no paradox, the math describing the physics allows this, that's a big point of CTCs.

Comment: @JMac no- what mainstream physics tells you that the particle continues to exist along all points on its trajectory? None!

Comment: What reasonable description of "time travel" would work the way you describe?  By your logic, you seem to suggest going backwards in time would take you to a world without any particles, because all the particles in the past (like yourself) have already moved past that point in time.  What mainstream physics uses that as the reason against theoretical time travel?  I cant say I've ever seen that way to refute it.

Comment: What's all this business about *traveling*? It's 4-space. A point-process  evolving in time in 3-space is a non-evolving curve-object in 4-space, an area-process  evolving in time is a  non-evolving volume-object in 4-space, and a volume-process evolving in time in 3-space is a  non-evolving hyperspace-object in 4-space. It doesn't *travel* anywhere or *do* anything, it just *is*.

Comment: If you can have a point-process in 3-space that is a *closed* curve-object in 4-space (and so on up through dimensions to a closed hypertube for a volume process in 3-space), then... that's what you can have. The cross-section of the hypertube at (r,t) is the cross-section of the hypertube at (r,t).

Comment: @JMac there is no reasonable process of time travel. Your idea of time travel is the stuff of movies etc.

Comment: @gs the worldliness, or world tube if you prefer, is the trajectory in 4 space. The object follows the trajectory. The object is not a 4 d sausage. What physics tells you that it is?

Comment: @JMac I agree that it is rather odd that you don't often see refutations of time travel expressed in those terms when it is such an obvious explanation.

Comment: @MarcoOcram Are you imagining what a Minkowski diagram with a dot moving along the worldline at a certain speed would look like if everything but the dot was invisible?

Comment: You misunderstand space-time.  Things do not "move through" it, they occupy worldlines.  The key concept you fail to understand is that spacetime INCLUDES TIME, hence all your "action" inferences to state sequencing are already included in the 4-space.

Comment: @dcleve I am sorry but you are talking unsubstantiated nonsense. I am a theoretical physicist, so I am not likely to have my views changed by the wielding of uppercase letters in a comment. Tell me any mainstream theoretical or experimental result in physics that tells you particles are 4d sausages rather than points following a trajectory.

Comment: marco -- So Einstein, Hawking, Smolin and Miller are all speaking nonsense, and the only people who understand time are you and Wikipedia??? Citations of oneself as an expert are not credible, particulary when you make freshman-level blunders in the subject.  Nobody considers particles to be "sausages" -- strawman bs like that does not get you  physics 101 credit.

Comment: @dcleve please address my point- tell me any mainstream physical result that says particles exist at all points along their world lines rather than tracing out their world lines.

Answer (score 0):

There's an interpretation of quantum mechanics where exactly this happens: [the transactional interpretation of quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_interpretation).

So yes, what you said is 100% with infinite sigfigs logically possible. There is nothing in the definition of causality that requires that causes temporally precede their effects.